# Implement website application with CNAME as a unique user

Tags: php, cname

I am currently building a product configurator on a website (example.com). The configurator will consist of products that you as a customer can put together to form a bundle.

This configurator will be available for dealers and on the website I will create a backend for them on the configurator website to login and style the configurator with their own logo, colors, etc.

I would like for the dealers to be able to implement their styled configurator on their own website and a way could be them setting up a subdomain (for example configurator.dealer.com) via a CNAME. The question is, how can I set this up, so each dealer gets their styled configurator shown on their own subdomain?

The CNAME setup has a name and a value. Name should be the subdomain name and the value somehow linking to the configurator with the dealer ID, key or alike. Can it be done by simply using an URL-parameter like example.com?userID=123 in the value and then use this parameter as GET on example.com to show the dealers configurator? Or can we setup a CNAME value in dealer backend that they should use when setting up DNS?

Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: _"Can it be done by simply using an URL-parameter like example.com?userID=123 in the value"_ - not, it can not - the value needs to be a host name. You should check the request hostname in your application, and associate that with the correct dealer ID.